# Plot points from any function on Time Series data in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm trying to plot points on any TS data. 
My main problem is how to transfer data to this function.
It should be able to plot points for this TS, i.e. 5% increase year to year

```
require(datasets)
require(zoo)
## ploting
MyPlot <- function(x=ldeaths,Events, pch = 19, col = 'red', cex = 1)
{ 
 plot(x)
 myData <- as.zoo(x)
 points(myData[Events], pch = pch, col = col, cex = cex)
  }

### My problem
MyPlot(x = anyTimeSeriesdata, Events = anyFunOperatingOnTS)
```

How to define `anyFunOperatingOnTS`?

Comment: This is a time series data so imagine that you want to plot the ts and then plot some specific points on ts plot. i.e. increase in sales month to month by more then 5%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this function. You can pass `percent = 0.05` for `>5%` or other value as necessary.

```
MyPlot <- function(x = ldeaths, Events = TRUE, pch = 19, col = 'red', 
                        cex = 1, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Deaths", percent = 0.05){     
    #Convert x to data.frame 
    intermediate_data = as.data.frame(t(matrix(x, 12,
                        dimnames = list(month.abb, unique(floor(time(x)))))))

    #Make year (from rownames) a column
    intermediate_data$year = rownames(intermediate_data)

    #Melt data into long form 
    require(reshape2)
    intermediate_data = melt(intermediate_data, id = "year")

    #Convert to POSIXct format (I've added 15 as day for each month)
    intermediate_data$date = as.POSIXct(paste(intermediate_data$year,
           intermediate_data$variable,"15",sep = "/"),format = "%Y/%b/%d")

    #Retain only the relevant columns                       
    intermediate_data = intermediate_data[,c(4,3)]

    #Order by date
    intermediate_data = intermediate_data[with(intermediate_data, order(date)), ]

    #Compute difference
    intermediate_data$diff = c(0,diff(x = intermediate_data$value,
                        lag = 1, differences = 1))

    #Find out the rows for which difference is greater than percent (default is 5%)
    for (i in 2:nrow(intermediate_data)){
        if (intermediate_data$diff[i]/intermediate_data$value[i-1] > percent){
            intermediate_data$Remarks[i] = paste(">",percent,sep="")
        } else {
            intermediate_data$Remarks[i] = paste("!>",percent,sep="")
        }
    }

    #Separate the ones with greater than 5% into another data.frame
    timeseries = subset(intermediate_data, 
             intermediate_data$Remarks == paste(">",percent,sep=""))

    #Plot the lines
    plot(x = intermediate_data$date, y = intermediate_data$value, 
                         type = "l", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)

    #Plot the points for greater than percent if EVENTS == TRUE
    if (Events == TRUE){
        points(x = timeseries$date, y = timeseries$value, 
                       pch = pch, col = col, cex = cex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Well written. Thank you.